# Running flash links offline

Tags: flash, navigatetourl

I have a flash file with some buttons, which open some http links using navigateToURL.

For example:

```
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, openPage)

function openPage(e:Event)
{
   navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.google.com"), "_blank")
}
```

It works fine on server, but when I try to run it offline/local, it does not open any link or shows any security info box.

My client needs to copy the whole website on a DVD and the buttons must open the live links(http).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the local playback security in Publish Settings:

By default, usually "Access local files only" is selected. This will prevent network locations from being accessed. Selecting 'Access network only' should fix the problem. If you need both, further instructions can be found in the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000457.html)

[image]